# How do I become a 'Good Sport' and what rewards can I receive?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

I received an in-game notification saying, "If you are a 'Good Sport' you will receive periodic rewards".  (see picture below)

[image]

**How do I become a 'Good Sport & what rewards can I receive?**

**How often will I receive rewards?**

I did get a notification when I *accidentally* blew up someone else's car, saying [something along the lines of]: "You blew up someones car.  You are a Poor Sport."

I also saw an in-game message that mentioned [something like] "If you are a Poor sport, you will play with other poor sports"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll become a "bad sport" by leaving missions/races/deatchmatches etc. early and destroying other player's personal vehicles.

The "bad sport" designation lasts for about 2 days. So if you want to be a "good sport" again, don't do things that are considered bad for 2 days.

I am not 100% sure what you can get as a reward. I once got a cash bonus of 1000$, but there could be more things (like discounts on ingame items).

Source: [IGN](http://www.ign.com/wikis/gta-5/Bad_Sports)

Comment: yeah you get $1000 once a day I think (48 minutes real time) but not sure what else (hence comment rather than answer)